# C# How to append only the end of text file and in specific position?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i want to change status from OK to NG,

```
IPen ID     Datetime                                Status
50      Wednesday, September 21, 2016 08:56:45      OK
IPen ID     Datetime                                Status
50      Wednesday, September 21, 2016 08:56:51      OK
```

this is file on my report.txt. my expectation is how we delete this last line with c# ?

```
IPen ID     Datetime                                Status
50      Wednesday, September 21, 2016 08:56:51      OK
```

and how to append OK status change into NG status? the result i hope is like this :

```
IPen ID     Datetime                                Status
50      Wednesday, September 21, 2016 08:56:45      NG
```

this is my code :

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(Fullpath);
File.WriteAllLines(Fullpath, lines.Take(lines.Length - 1).ToArray());
DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, lines[lines.Length - 1]);

var text = new StringBuilder();

foreach (string s in File.ReadAllLines(Fullpath))
{
    text.AppendLine(s.Replace("OK", "NG"));
}

using (var file = new StreamWriter(File.Create(Fullpath)))
{
    file.Write(text.ToString());
}
```

this code will append all of "OK" change into "NG". not like that i want, but i want to delete the last result and change only two last result from "OK" to "NG" not all OK change to NG. any suggestion or solution for me? thanks for attention and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already reading the entire file into memory, you could convert it to a list, remove from the end, and iterate in reverse to update the last two entries:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(Fullpath).ToList();

// Remove as many lines as you'd like from the end
if (lines.Count > 2)
{
    lines.RemoveRange(lines.Count - 2, 2);
}

// Iterate backwards through the list until we've updated 2 (or more or less) lines
var linesUpdated = 0;

for (var i = lines.Count - 1; i >= 0 && linesUpdated < 2; i--)
{
    if (lines[i].Contains("OK"))
    {
        lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("OK", "NG");
        linesUpdated++;
    }
}

File.WriteAllLines(Fullpath, lines.ToArray());
```

Comment: i test your code but my vstudio show 2 error message is :

Comment: Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string[]'

Comment: 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Which .NET version are you targeting? You could always call lines.ToArray().

Comment: I see. 4.5 has additional overloads. Try: File.WriteAllLines(Fullpath, lines.ToArray());

Answer (score 2):

Instead of updating all lines, determine the last line and then update.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(Fullpath);
File.WriteAllLines(Fullpath, lines.Take(lines.Length - 1).ToArray());
DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, lines[lines.Length - 1]);

var text = new StringBuilder();
var data = File.ReadAllLines(Fullpath);
var lines = data.Take(data.Count() - 2);
var last = lines.Last();

foreach (string s in lines)
{
    if(s.Equals(last))
    {
        text.AppendLine(s.Replace("OK", "NG"));
    }
    else
    {
        text.AppendLine(s);
    }
}

using (var file = new StreamWriter(File.Create(Fullpath)))
{
    file.Write(text.ToString());
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

simplistic approach :-

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
if (lines.Length > 0)
{
  lines[lines.Length - 1] = lines[lines.Length - 1].Replace("OK", "NG");
}
File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```

to remove last two lines

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList().Take(lines.Count-2).ToArray())
```

But you probably want to start parsing the lines into objects, make whatever changes to your objects, then serializing them back out as lines of text

Comment: for the case of replace OK to NG your answer is really good one sir, but the first is i delete last line after that i change the OK to NG, how about delete the two last line sir ?

Comment: i am using target framework 3.5 . that show error sir.

Comment: do you have...  `using System.Collections.Generic;  `   at the top?

Comment: Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'

Answer (score 1):

You can't "Append" Over something.

You need to read in the whole file into an array of strings (one for each line) then alter the lines you want, then re-write the whole contents over the existing file.

```
// Read in whole contents of file.
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(Fullpath);

// Alter the lines you want to.
//Remove the last two rows (headers and data)
if (lines.Length > 2) lines = lines.ToList().Take(lines.Length - 2).ToArray();

// If lines contains 1 or more line in the file, replace any occurrence of OK, with NG.
if (lines.Length >= 1) lines[lines.Length - 1] = lines[lines.Length - 1].Replace("OK", "NG");

// Now write the contents of the file you have here in RAM back over the original file.
File.WriteAllLines(Fullpath, lines);
```

I would suggest a more robust way of editing these logs. It would be problematic if the records being written were later changed to include two columns that wrote out a value of `OK`. In this case, you would alter them both.
Alternatives to this are:

- As @[keith-nicholas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10431/keith-nicholas) suggested, seriealize your data into an object and use that for editing.
- Or get the column starting location from the line above the line you are editing. Then use that as a reference point. 
  For Instance, to edit the last line:

  ```
  // This assumes those column headers are above each line
  if (lines.Length >= 2)
  {
      // Get the string starting location of the [Status] column
      int index = lines[lines.Length - 2].IndexOf("Status");

      // Now replace the text under that Status Column in the next row
      // Remove the OK characters (first two)
      lines[lines.Length - 1] = lines[lines.Length - 1].Remove(index, 2);
      // Then Insert the two characters you want
      lines[lines.Length - 1] = lines[lines.Length - 1].Insert(index, "NG");
  }
  ```

Comment: for the case of replace OK to NG your answer is really good one sir, but the first is i delete last line after that i change the OK to NG, how about delete the two last line sir ?

Comment: You'll see I edit the last two lines before writing back out. This updates them both

Comment: no, i am not want to update them both, but i want delete one and update only one. delete the last and update the two of last line sir.